# How to read a file one line at a time and pass each line to a struct in C?

Tags: c, file, struct

I am trying to create two methods in C. One method that opens a file and reads it one line at a time each time it's called, the other method takes in a line and puts certain information from that line into a struct. I have the struct method mostly working but I cannot figure out how to make the first method only read one line at a time and pass it. I have only been successful in making it read the entire file all at once with a buffer. My current work is below:

```
//First method
char * GimmeALine(int FD){

static char buf[BUFFSIZE];

ssize_t nchr = 0;
ssize_t idx = 0;
off_t *offset = 0;
char *p = NULL;
ssize_t *len;

if((nchr = lseek(FD, *offset, SEEK_SET)) !=-1)
  nchr = read(FD, buf, sizeof(buf));
(close(FD));

if(nchr == -1){
    err_sys("File read error");
}

  if(nchr == 0) return NULL;

  p = buf;
  while(idx < nchr && *p != '\n') p++, idx++;
  *p = 0;

  if(idx == nchr){
    *offset += nchr;

    return NULL;
    }

   *offset += idx +1;
   *len = idx;
   return buf;
}
//Main used for testing
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 1024

//Prototypes
char* GimmeALine(int FD);
struct Country *FillAStruct(char * Line);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  

  int file;
  char* line;
  file = open("AllCountries.dat", O_RDONLY);  //Opens the in file
  if(file == -1){
    err_sys("File open error");
  }

   GimmeALine(file);
   close(file);
  return 0;
}
```

As part of the assignment, we were required to use the open(), read(), and close() functions instead of their easier f counterparts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you are not allowed to use formatted read functions, you read one `buf` worth of information at a time. You then will parse the buffer manually. Step through it a character at a time. When you find a `'\n'`, you have just found the end of a line. **NOTE** since you are using *string* functions in `FillAStruct` you *must* insure *all* strings passed through `Line` are **null-terminated**.

Comment: Where is `buf` coming from in `GimmeALine`? Go read (and re-read) my last comment about scope following my answer and make sure you understand it completely before moving on -- it is fundamental to C programming. Ask if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of observations. (1) you can never return a pointer to an array of characters from a function where you *statically declare* the array *within* the function. Why? When the function returns, its address space is destroyed -- meaning *your* `buf` will no longer exist in memory when you return from your `char *` function. (there are several finer points and work-arounds not relevant here). Your primary choices are to either (a) pass a sufficiently sized array as an argument to your function, or (b) dynamically allocate space for `buf` in your function. I'll show you (a) below.

Next, about your coding style... While not an error, the C standard style avoids the use of `Initial-caps` and `caMelCase` labels (variable names, struct names, etc.) in favor of all lower-case. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf) Again, this isn't an error, but an area where you are paddling up-stream...

Following from the comment, with `read`, you are limited to reading up to some `fixed` number of bytes from the file descriptor, without any reference to what the individual characters actually are. `read` will simply read what is available up to a max of the size specified. This means it is up to you to parse each line out of the `buf` used to store what is read.

That in itself isn't difficult, simply use a pointer to `buf` and loop until you find a `newline` or reach the last character read. However, you do need some way of keeping track where you are within the file so you don't end up reading the same first line over-and-over each time you call your read function. Passing a pointer to your file `offset` that is updated during each call can help you keep track of where you are. (think of it as an *end-pointer* pointing to the next character to be read from the file on each successive call)

You will also need to read the man page for `read` and pay close attention to the various return values that are possible. There are many more you can utilize than the brief subset shown below.

Lastly, what follows is simply an example of one approach to reading a `'line'` from a text file with `open / read` each time the function is called. How you split the line up after you make the call is left up to you. Let me know if you get stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSZ 128

ssize_t readline (char *buf, size_t sz, char *fn, off_t *offset);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) return 1;

    char line[BUFSZ] = {0};
    off_t offset = 0;
    ssize_t len = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    /* using open/read, read each line in file into 'line' */
    while ((len = readline (line, BUFSZ, argv[1], &offset)) != -1)
        printf (" line[%2zu] : %s (%zd chars)\n", i++, line, len);

    return 0;
}

/* read 'sz' bytes from file 'fn' beginning at file 'offset'
   storing all chars  in 'buf', where 'buf' is terminated at
   the first newline found. On success, returns number of 
   characters read, -1 on error or EOF with 0 chars read.
*/
ssize_t readline (char *buf, size_t sz, char *fn, off_t *offset)
{
    int fd = open (fn, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) { 
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: file open failed '%s'.\n",
                __func__, fn);
        return -1;
    }

    ssize_t nchr = 0;
    ssize_t idx = 0;
    char *p = NULL;

    /* position fd & read line */
    if ((nchr = lseek (fd, *offset, SEEK_SET)) != -1)
        nchr = read (fd, buf, sz);
    close (fd);

    if (nchr == -1) {   /* read error   */
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: read failure in '%s'.\n",
                __func__, fn);
        return nchr;
    }

    /* end of file - no chars read
       (not an error, but return -1 )*/
    if (nchr == 0) return -1;

    p = buf;    /* check each chacr */
    while (idx < nchr && *p != '\n') p++, idx++;
    *p = 0;

    if (idx == nchr) {  /* newline not found  */
        *offset += nchr;

        /* check file missing newline at end */
        return nchr < (ssize_t)sz ? nchr : 0;
    }

    *offset += idx + 1;

    return idx;
}
```

**Example Input**

The following datafiles are identical except the second contains a *blank line* between each line of text.

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.

$ cat dat/captnjack2.txt
This is a tale

Of Captain Jack Sparrow

A Pirate So Brave

On the Seven Seas.
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/readfile dat/captnjack.txt
 line[ 0] : This is a tale (14 chars)
 line[ 1] : Of Captain Jack Sparrow (23 chars)
 line[ 2] : A Pirate So Brave (17 chars)
 line[ 3] : On the Seven Seas. (18 chars)

$ ./bin/readfile dat/captnjack2.txt
 line[ 0] : This is a tale (14 chars)
 line[ 1] :  (0 chars)
 line[ 2] : Of Captain Jack Sparrow (23 chars)
 line[ 3] :  (0 chars)
 line[ 4] : A Pirate So Brave (17 chars)
 line[ 5] :  (0 chars)
 line[ 6] : On the Seven Seas. (18 chars)
```

**Returning 'char *'**

Here is a quick update that changes the return of `readline` to `char *` and the other changes required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSZ 128

char *readline (int fd, char *buf, size_t sz, off_t *offset, size_t *len);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) return 1;

    int fd = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) { 
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    char line[BUFSZ] = {0};
    off_t offset = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    /* using open/read, read each line in file into 'line' */
    while (readline (fd, line, BUFSZ, &offset, &len)) {
        printf (" line[%2zu] : %s (%zd chars)\n", i++, line, len);
        len = 0;
    }

    close (fd);

    return 0;
}

/* read 'sz' bytes from file 'fd' beginning at file 'offset'
   storing all chars  in 'buf', where 'buf' is terminated at
   the first newline found. On success, returns pointer to 
   buf, otherwise NULL on error or EOF with 0 chars read.
*/
char *readline (int fd, char *buf, size_t sz, off_t *offset, size_t *len)
{
    ssize_t nchr = 0;
    ssize_t idx = 0;
    char *p = NULL;

    /* set file position indicator */
    if ((lseek (fd, *offset, SEEK_SET)) == -1) {    /* lseek error   */
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: seek failure (FD '%d').\n",
                __func__, fd);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* read 'sz' bytes from 'fd' */
    if ((nchr = read (fd, buf, sz)) == -1) {   /* read error   */
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: read failure (FD '%d').\n",
                __func__, fd);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* end of file - no chars read */
    if (nchr == 0) return NULL;

    p = buf;    /* check each char */
    while (idx < nchr && *p != '\n') p++, idx++;
    *p = 0;

    if (idx == nchr) {  /* newline not found  */
        *offset += nchr;
        *len = nchr;
        *buf = 0;       /* set buf as empty-string for return */

        return NULL;
    }

    *len = idx;         /* set length   */
    *offset += idx + 1; /* set offset   */

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Alright I have implemented some of your suggestions and believe I have made some decent progress in the program, however, the return type for the "GimmeALine" method has to be a char *(as per the assignment requirement). This is so it can be passed and used with the "FillAStruct" method. How would I go about returning a char * that points to the line the method just read?

Comment: I just realized also that the "GimmeALine" method has to be passed a file descriptor so it does not have to open the file inside of itself, it must only return the next line of an open file that it reads. The file descriptor is given to it from main.

Comment: Changing the return is simple, just have it `return buf;`. This means to git the length, you will need to pass another pointer.  Add `size_t *len` at the end of the parameter list, and then set `*len = idx;` before the `return buf;` (you will also need to adjust the remaining returns to return a pointer , e.g. `return NULL;` on error instead of `-1`, etc.)

Comment: Okay I have made your suggested changes but now I am getting segmentation faults when I try to test the method.

Comment: Take a look at the edits. You generally receive a segfault when you try and write beyond the allocated (or declared) size of an array, etc.

Comment: What you should learn at the 'overview' level from the rewrite to `char *`, is that C is incredibly flexible, allowing you to write functions that do, take as parameters, and return, exactly what you want because you are coding at an extremely low-level. You are not stuck with 'just what the function does' as you are in some languages -- because you are the one writing the functions in C. C provides you with the tools to control every aspect of a computer -- how you put them together is up to you...

Comment: I'm looking at your edits -- and what you are missing is a lesson in `scope`. You only have 2 ways (1 primary) to get information back from a function. You can get the `return` (if dynamically allocated) or you can update pointer values (e.g. updating `len` by passing `&len` to the function). You **CANNOT** declare a string with static storage in a function and return a pointer value to that string to `main`. Why? When the function returns, its address space is wiped clean (including any variable you declared in the function). So you **MUST** pass or allocate anything you expect back!